# Convert rows of a column to an expression

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("x^2", "y^2", "z^2"), B=c(1,2,3))
```

How can I convert `A` rows into an `expression`?

```
    A           B
expression(x^2) 1
expression(y^2) 2
expression(z^2) 3
```

I tried:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(A = expression(A))
```

but it gives me an error: `A must be a vector, not an expression vector.`

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
> df %>% mutate(A = lapply(A, as.expression))
                  A B
1 expression("x^2") 1
2 expression("y^2") 2
3 expression("z^2") 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`expression()` does not evaluate its arguments, so it will not get your desired result where the input is changed to expressions.

`as.expression()` (like noted already by @ThomasIsCoding) would be the first thing to consider if you have a pre-existing vector of things you want to turn into an expression vector. However, the expressions you have above will evaluate to simple character strings like `"x^2"`.

I assume that is not the intended result - you would not need expressions to just store some character strings. So the remedy would be to remove the quotation marks. But you can't just straight up enter `x^2` without quotation marks into your data frame, you would have to pass it as an expression vector - so now we are stuck in a loop, hen or egg problem.

But, luckily, `str2expression()` exists to make your life easier. It takes character strings as an input, removes the quotation marks and turns them into an expression vector.

```r
x <- 2
y <- 4
z <- 6

df <- data.frame(A=c("x^2", "y^2", "z^2"), B=c(1,2,3))

(df$C <- as.expression(df$A))
#> expression("x^2", "y^2", "z^2")
sapply(df$C, eval)
#> [1] "x^2" "y^2" "z^2"

(df$D <- str2expression(df$A))
#> expression(x^2, y^2, z^2)
sapply(df$D, eval)
#> [1]  4 16 36
```